# User defined file types to replace defaults

Tags: bash

I am setting default values for file types, but when the user specifies his own filetypes, I want to disregard the defaults, rather than appending.  What can I do to fix this?  This is part of a bash script.

```
local incl=( ".rc" ".el" ".c" ".f")
while (( $# > 0 )); do
  opt="$1"
  case $opt in
   ("--FS") fs="$2" ; shift ; shift ;;
   ("--incl") incl+=("$2") ; shift ; shift ;;
   (*) break ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
local incl

while (( $# > 0 )); do
  case $1 in
   (--FS) fs=$2;;
   (--incl) incl+=("$2");;
   (*) break ;;
   shift 2
  esac
done

((${#incl[@]} == 0 )) &&
incl=(.rc .el .c .f)
```

If you have to add any single word options, change `shift 2` to `shift`, and add an extra shift to commands for double word options.

Comment: How can one delete an entry from the array?

Comment: @Dilna selecting the element by value or by index? `unset arr[N]` deletes index and value (without changing other indexes). To select by value, you'll need to loop over the array to delete it properly. Why do you want to delete? There's probably a better approach.